# Unity3D WWW call on main thread on iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, unity-game-engine

In the app we're making, we want to do attempt a remote user save data when the app suspends.  In Unity's Editor, and on Android, this is as simple as

```
WWW www = new WWW(_URL);
while(!www.isDone)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
Debug.Log(www.text);
```

(full sample: https://github.com/SixMinute/iOSWWWGet)

But on iOS, `www.isDone` never evaluates to true while we're blocking, so the whole thing just hangs.

Is this a bug, or by design?  And then if it's by design, what's the proper way to do it, because if we put this behind a `StartCoroutine`, it's not properly on the main thread, and on suspend, what's happening gets pushed to when the app resumes (which completely defeats the purpose of what we're trying to do).

edit: After talking to some of the Unity devs on IRC, they accept that this is actually a bug in the code, understand my reasons for needing this, and accept there needs to be a way to synchronously fire a WWW request, or some other way to enable this when called during the flow of a `OnApplicationPause(true)` on iOS, because otherwise (despite being able to easily do it natively) there's no way to fire WWW requests at that time, the only option is to queue them until resume, which is completely impracticable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment Unity does not start a new thread for www action, at least on some platforms (iOS, webplayer). Or if it does, it sets WWW.isDone on the main thread. So this code:

```
while(!www.isDone)
     Thread.Sleep(500);
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I've added the response from the Unity iOS devs.  While this is a limitation of the platform in this instance, there's still got to be a way to fire WWW requests during the suspend flow, from a `OnApplicationPause(true)` call.  In the simplest form at the moment, your response is correct, and I'll mark it as such, but hopefully Unity fix the bug / allow a way to do this on iOS, and I'll add that method as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Start your www call in any method you want.  During update, check for www.isDone... if that returns true, then act upon it... otherwise pass through.

```
private WWW myRequest = null;

void Update()
{
    if (myRequest != null)
    {
        if (myRequest.isDone)
        {
            // process request here

            myRequest = null;// reset it 
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to support firing more than one www request at once, put your www requests in an array List myRequests = new List() and loop through those in the update instead and check for each one's status.  You can't remove from myRequests while your using it, so note the temp remove list.

```
private List<WWW> myRequests = new List<WWW>()

void Update()
{
    if (myRequests.Count > 0)
    {
        List<WWW> removeList = null;

        foreach (WWW myRequest in myRequests)
        {
            if (myRequest.isDone)
            {
                // process request here

                if (removeList == null)
                {
                    removeList = new List<WWW>();
                }
                removeList.Add(myRequest);
            }
        }
        if (removeList != null)
        {
            foreach (WWW oldReq in removeList)
            {
                myRequests.Remove(oldReq);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this on [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-isDone.html)

Use a Coroutine, while loop will be blocked on web player:

```
void SaveDate()
{
StartCoroutine("SaveWebData");
}

IEnumerator SaveWebData() 
{
// Start a download of the given URL
WWW www = new WWW(_URL);

// Wait for download to complete
yield return www;

// Completed!
Debug.Log(www.text);
}
```

Comment: Can you supply some code because that page is incredibly lacking information and, *as I said*, using `StartCoroutine` pushes anything that happens after the `yield` to when the app resumes.  I need the download to occur like it does in the Editor, and on Android, on the main thread.

Comment: _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_.  Consider editing your answer to contain a summary of the article pointed to by the link.

Comment: It's a better answer alright, but you clearly didn't read the question, "because if we put this behind a `StartCoroutine`, it's not properly on the main thread, and on suspend, what's happening gets pushed to when the app resumes (which completely defeats the purpose of what we're trying to do).".  *Nor* did you read the title, talking about it being on iOS.